# Accomplishments script CPU usage

Tags: cpu-load, accomplishments

Since I installed Ubuntu accomplishments again in 12.10 I constantly have about 15% CPU usage by the script

```
/usr/share/accomplishments/scripts/ubuntu-desktop/multimedia/multimedia-added-music.py
```

I can kill it but it comes back on reboot. Does someone know a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can be closed because it is a bug and therefore off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in this script. Can you please [report it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-community-accomplishments/+filebug) so that we'll remember to investigate it?

Comment: done: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-community-accomplishments/+bug/1108285